# How come the CSS in my JavaScript won't work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a box pop up when i click on it. Here is the HTML for the boxes:

```
<div id="content_1">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Please push the button</p>
    <p><input type="button" id="go_button" value="Go"/> </p>
</div>
<div id="box">
    <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript and CSS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content_2").on("click",function(){
    .css("z-index",3);
    }
}
```

Here is the styling just in case it's needed:

```
#go_button {

}
#content_1 {
margin:20px auto;
position:fixed;
width:1000px;
text-align:center;
border:1px solid #d0d0d0;
box-shadow:1px 1px 5px #aaa;
border-radius:15px;
background:#99FF99;
z-index:3;
}
#box {
position:fixed;
top:100px;
left:300px;
z-index:1;
width:600px;
height:300px;
background:green;
}
body {
background:#f7f7f7;
}
```

Comment: `<p>hello</>` has a typo, not sure if that would have any negative impact.

Comment: Well for one, you can't just do `.css("z-index",3);`...

Comment: Please use your webdeveloper console (F12) next time... so many errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you aren't applying the css to anything:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#content_2").on("click",function(){
        $('#box').css("z-index",3);
    }
}
```

Also, `#content_2` isn't defined.

Comment: i know... accident instead of $content_2/#content_@ it's $box/$box

Answer (score 4):

You cannot call a method chain without anything to start it.   We don't see an element with the id `content_2` in your markup.  Perhaps you mean to apply this to `#content_1`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content_2").on("click",function(){
        // Apply to this
        $(this).css("z-index",3);
    });
});
```

If the CSS is to be applied to some other element rather than `content_2` (`this`), use its selector instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content_2").on("click",function(){
        $('#box').css("z-index",3);
    });
});
```

Note that unless you have specified  `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`, that `z-index` won't have any effect.

Comment: Also, I'm betting he also didn't position his div, so z-index is meaningless.

Comment: @th3w01f98 `position: absolute;` is needed for the z-index to be of use.

Comment: @th3w01f98 correct your typo! You bind the click to `#content_2` - it should be `#content_1`, no?

Comment: @th3w01f98 Reading your question over, I guess it is `#box` you want to raise, not `#content_2` (`this`)

Comment: i want to be that when u click the 2 divs the one u click comes up because it has a higher z-index

Comment: @Michael I guess it should be: `$("#content_1 input").on("click",function(){
    $("#box").css...`

Comment: There's also missing closing parenthesis for `.on` and `.ready`

Comment: @th3w01f98 You need to open your browser's debugging console and look for errors. There were multiple syntactic problems identified by commenters and myself.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $("box").on("click",function(){
    $(this).css("z-index",3);
    }
}

Comment: @th3w01f98 That is missing two closing parentheses. See my examples above.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $("box").on("click",function(){
    $(this).css("z-index",3);

Comment: @th3w01f98 We cannot debug your code, when it isn't all in front of us. I suggest you use a tool like jsfiddle.net to create a mock-up.  Anything beyond what you've been provided already is outside the scope of your original question, and would belong in  a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content_2").on("click",function(){
    $(this).css("z-index",3);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but it didn't work; the div isn't in a position:fixed so idk why it not working